# Change CSS of class without affecting others

Tags: html, css, class

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
```

How can I change the background of this for a single page, so it will not be applied to every page.

Thanks for help.

Comment: write the styles using <style> inside the particular page. so other pages it will not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you can add an ID to this div and add some css, or add some inline css. For example:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="...">
```

Or:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="...">
<style>#...</style>
```

Comment: This is more inline with a class, as we are technically inheriting the properties then shadowing one of them.

Comment: You can always write #a.b{color:red}. It will be even better than using more class because the id make it unique and individual.

Comment: I know you can. But an id is an id. This is object inheritance, thus using a class is better suited.

Answer (score 3):

insert your on class in that div for that single page

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top my_navbar" role="navigation">
```

css may be:

```
.my_navbar{
 background-color:blue;
```

}

Comment: Changing the div class would remove current style that is already in an external css file. an Inline Style worked. Many thanks for help.